# Lazyload background-image

Tags: html, css, image, background, lazy-loading

```
.banner{
  background: cloudinary-url("images_mobile/buy_gift_cards/buy-giftcard-banner.png", $secure: true, $fetch_format: "auto", $quality: "auto", $flags: "lossy");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  height:200px;
  background-size:auto 100%;
}
<div class="banner">

</div>
```

[Using this github lazysizes](http://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)

Can Anyone help how to implement lazyload in this?

Comment: using that link the tell you exactly what to do?

Comment: Yes by lazysizes repo

Answer (score 1):

What i did was i used their JavaScript and got the Unminify version using this [link](http://unminify.com/). Then Removed your `css` and added an image tag to `HTML` as their documentation , with the image tag having a class called `class="lazyload"`.

**What you need to do:**

Just firstly download the script file, add it to your `js` directory. Then link the file to your webpage `HTML` in as script tag like this:

```
 <head>
    <script src="yourdirectory/lazysizes.min.js" async=""></script>
 </head>
```

Then add the `img` tag with the  class `class="lazyload"`.

> After these steps it should be implemented and working.

```js
! function(a, b) {
    var c = b(a, a.document);
    a.lazySizes = c, "object" == typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = c)
}(window, function(a, b) {
    "use strict";
    if (b.getElementsByClassName) {
        var c, d, e = b.documentElement,
            f = a.Date,
            g = a.HTMLPictureElement,
            h = "addEventListener",
            i = "getAttribute",
            j = a[h],
            k = a.setTimeout,
            l = a.requestAnimationFrame || k,
            m = a.requestIdleCallback,
            n = /^picture$/i,
            o = ["load", "error", "lazyincluded", "_lazyloaded"],
            p = {},
            q = Array.prototype.forEach,
            r = function(a, b) {
                return p[b] || (p[b] = new RegExp("(\\s|^)" + b + "(\\s|$)")), p[b].test(a[i]("class") || "") && p[b]
            },
            s = function(a, b) {
                r(a, b) || a.setAttribute("class", (a[i]("class") || "").trim() + " " + b)
            },
            t = function(a, b) {
                var c;
                (c = r(a, b)) && a.setAttribute("class", (a[i]("class") || "").replace(c, " "))
            },
            u = function(a, b, c) {
                var d = c ? h : "removeEventListener";
                c && u(a, b), o.forEach(function(c) {
                    a[d](c, b)
                })
            },
            v = function(a, d, e, f, g) {
                var h = b.createEvent("CustomEvent");
                return e || (e = {}), e.instance = c, h.initCustomEvent(d, !f, !g, e), a.dispatchEvent(h), h
            },
            w = function(b, c) {
                var e;
                !g && (e = a.picturefill || d.pf) ? e({
                    reevaluate: !0,
                    elements: [b]
                }) : c && c.src && (b.src = c.src)
            },
            x = function(a, b) {
                return (getComputedStyle(a, null) || {})[b]
            },
            y = function(a, b, c) {
                for (c = c || a.offsetWidth; c < d.minSize && b && !a._lazysizesWidth;) c = b.offsetWidth, b = b.parentNode;
                return c
            },
            z = function() {
                var a, c, d = [],
                    e = [],
                    f = d,
                    g = function() {
                        var b = f;
                        for (f = d.length ? e : d, a = !0, c = !1; b.length;) b.shift()();
                        a = !1
                    },
                    h = function(d, e) {
                        a && !e ? d.apply(this, arguments) : (f.push(d), c || (c = !0, (b.hidden ? k : l)(g)))
                    };
                return h._lsFlush = g, h
            }(),
            A = function(a, b) {
                return b ? function() {
                    z(a)
                } : function() {
                    var b = this,
                        c = arguments;
                    z(function() {
                        a.apply(b, c)
                    })
                }
            },
            B = function(a) {
                var b, c = 0,
                    e = 125,
                    g = d.ricTimeout,
                    h = function() {
                        b = !1, c = f.now(), a()
                    },
                    i = m && d.ricTimeout ? function() {
                        m(h, {
                            timeout: g
                        }), g !== d.ricTimeout && (g = d.ricTimeout)
                    } : A(function() {
                        k(h)
                    }, !0);
                return function(a) {
                    var d;
                    (a = a === !0) && (g = 33), b || (b = !0, d = e - (f.now() - c), 0 > d && (d = 0), a || 9 > d && m ? i() : k(i, d))
                }
            },
            C = function(a) {
                var b, c, d = 99,
                    e = function() {
                        b = null, a()
                    },
                    g = function() {
                        var a = f.now() - c;
                        d > a ? k(g, d - a) : (m || e)(e)
                    };
                return function() {
                    c = f.now(), b || (b = k(g, d))
                }
            };
        ! function() {
            var b, c = {
                lazyClass: "lazyload",
                loadedClass: "lazyloaded",
                loadingClass: "lazyloading",
                preloadClass: "lazypreload",
                errorClass: "lazyerror",
                autosizesClass: "lazyautosizes",
                srcAttr: "data-src",
                srcsetAttr: "data-srcset",
                sizesAttr: "data-sizes",
                minSize: 40,
                customMedia: {},
                init: !0,
                expFactor: 1.5,
                hFac: .8,
                loadMode: 2,
                loadHidden: !0,
                ricTimeout: 300
            };
            d = a.lazySizesConfig || a.lazysizesConfig || {};
            for (b in c) b in d || (d[b] = c[b]);
            a.lazySizesConfig = d, k(function() {
                d.init && F()
            })
        }();
        var D = function() {
                var g, l, m, o, p, y, D, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M = /^img$/i,
                    N = /^iframe$/i,
                    O = "onscroll" in a && !/glebot/.test(navigator.userAgent),
                    P = 0,
                    Q = 0,
                    R = 0,
                    S = -1,
                    T = function(a) {
                        R--, a && a.target && u(a.target, T), (!a || 0 > R || !a.target) && (R = 0)
                    },
                    U = function(a, c) {
                        var d, f = a,
                            g = "hidden" == x(b.body, "visibility") || "hidden" != x(a, "visibility");
                        for (F -= c, I += c, G -= c, H += c; g && (f = f.offsetParent) && f != b.body && f != e;) g = (x(f, "opacity") || 1) > 0, g && "visible" != x(f, "overflow") && (d = f.getBoundingClientRect(), g = H > d.left && G < d.right && I > d.top - 1 && F < d.bottom + 1);
                        return g
                    },
                    V = function() {
                        var a, f, h, j, k, m, n, p, q, r = c.elements;
                        if ((o = d.loadMode) && 8 > R && (a = r.length)) {
                            f = 0, S++, null == K && ("expand" in d || (d.expand = e.clientHeight > 500 && e.clientWidth > 500 ? 500 : 370), J = d.expand, K = J * d.expFactor), K > Q && 1 > R && S > 2 && o > 2 && !b.hidden ? (Q = K, S = 0) : Q = o > 1 && S > 1 && 6 > R ? J : P;
                            for (; a > f; f++)
                                if (r[f] && !r[f]._lazyRace)
                                    if (O)
                                        if ((p = r[f][i]("data-expand")) && (m = 1 * p) || (m = Q), q !== m && (y = innerWidth + m * L, D = innerHeight + m, n = -1 * m, q = m), h = r[f].getBoundingClientRect(), (I = h.bottom) >= n && (F = h.top) <= D && (H = h.right) >= n * L && (G = h.left) <= y && (I || H || G || F) && (d.loadHidden || "hidden" != x(r[f], "visibility")) && (l && 3 > R && !p && (3 > o || 4 > S) || U(r[f], m))) {
                                            if (ba(r[f]), k = !0, R > 9) break
                                        } else !k && l && !j && 4 > R && 4 > S && o > 2 && (g[0] || d.preloadAfterLoad) && (g[0] || !p && (I || H || G || F || "auto" != r[f][i](d.sizesAttr))) && (j = g[0] || r[f]);
                            else ba(r[f]);
                            j && !k && ba(j)
                        }
                    },
                    W = B(V),
                    X = function(a) {
                        s(a.target, d.loadedClass), t(a.target, d.loadingClass), u(a.target, Z), v(a.target, "lazyloaded")
                    },
                    Y = A(X),
                    Z = function(a) {
                        Y({
                            target: a.target
                        })
                    },
                    $ = function(a, b) {
                        try {
                            a.contentWindow.location.replace(b)
                        } catch (c) {
                            a.src = b
                        }
                    },
                    _ = function(a) {
                        var b, c = a[i](d.srcsetAttr);
                        (b = d.customMedia[a[i]("data-media") || a[i]("media")]) && a.setAttribute("media", b), c && a.setAttribute("srcset", c)
                    },
                    aa = A(function(a, b, c, e, f) {
                        var g, h, j, l, o, p;
                        (o = v(a, "lazybeforeunveil", b)).defaultPrevented || (e && (c ? s(a, d.autosizesClass) : a.setAttribute("sizes", e)), h = a[i](d.srcsetAttr), g = a[i](d.srcAttr), f && (j = a.parentNode, l = j && n.test(j.nodeName || "")), p = b.firesLoad || "src" in a && (h || g || l), o = {
                            target: a
                        }, p && (u(a, T, !0), clearTimeout(m), m = k(T, 2500), s(a, d.loadingClass), u(a, Z, !0)), l && q.call(j.getElementsByTagName("source"), _), h ? a.setAttribute("srcset", h) : g && !l && (N.test(a.nodeName) ? $(a, g) : a.src = g), f && (h || l) && w(a, {
                            src: g
                        })), a._lazyRace && delete a._lazyRace, t(a, d.lazyClass), z(function() {
                            (!p || a.complete && a.naturalWidth > 1) && (p ? T(o) : R--, X(o))
                        }, !0)
                    }),
                    ba = function(a) {
                        var b, c = M.test(a.nodeName),
                            e = c && (a[i](d.sizesAttr) || a[i]("sizes")),
                            f = "auto" == e;
                        (!f && l || !c || !a[i]("src") && !a.srcset || a.complete || r(a, d.errorClass) || !r(a, d.lazyClass)) && (b = v(a, "lazyunveilread").detail, f && E.updateElem(a, !0, a.offsetWidth), a._lazyRace = !0, R++, aa(a, b, f, e, c))
                    },
                    ca = function() {
                        if (!l) {
                            if (f.now() - p < 999) return void k(ca, 999);
                            var a = C(function() {
                                d.loadMode = 3, W()
                            });
                            l = !0, d.loadMode = 3, W(), j("scroll", function() {
                                3 == d.loadMode && (d.loadMode = 2), a()
                            }, !0)
                        }
                    };
                return {
                    _: function() {
                        p = f.now(), c.elements = b.getElementsByClassName(d.lazyClass), g = b.getElementsByClassName(d.lazyClass + " " + d.preloadClass), L = d.hFac, j("scroll", W, !0), j("resize", W, !0), a.MutationObserver ? new MutationObserver(W).observe(e, {
                            childList: !0,
                            subtree: !0,
                            attributes: !0
                        }) : (e[h]("DOMNodeInserted", W, !0), e[h]("DOMAttrModified", W, !0), setInterval(W, 999)), j("hashchange", W, !0), ["focus", "mouseover", "click", "load", "transitionend", "animationend", "webkitAnimationEnd"].forEach(function(a) {
                            b[h](a, W, !0)
                        }), /d$|^c/.test(b.readyState) ? ca() : (j("load", ca), b[h]("DOMContentLoaded", W), k(ca, 2e4)), c.elements.length ? (V(), z._lsFlush()) : W()
                    },
                    checkElems: W,
                    unveil: ba
                }
            }(),
            E = function() {
                var a, c = A(function(a, b, c, d) {
                        var e, f, g;
                        if (a._lazysizesWidth = d, d += "px", a.setAttribute("sizes", d), n.test(b.nodeName || ""))
                            for (e = b.getElementsByTagName("source"), f = 0, g = e.length; g > f; f++) e[f].setAttribute("sizes", d);
                        c.detail.dataAttr || w(a, c.detail)
                    }),
                    e = function(a, b, d) {
                        var e, f = a.parentNode;
                        f && (d = y(a, f, d), e = v(a, "lazybeforesizes", {
                            width: d,
                            dataAttr: !!b
                        }), e.defaultPrevented || (d = e.detail.width, d && d !== a._lazysizesWidth && c(a, f, e, d)))
                    },
                    f = function() {
                        var b, c = a.length;
                        if (c)
                            for (b = 0; c > b; b++) e(a[b])
                    },
                    g = C(f);
                return {
                    _: function() {
                        a = b.getElementsByClassName(d.autosizesClass), j("resize", g)
                    },
                    checkElems: g,
                    updateElem: e
                }
            }(),
            F = function() {
                F.i || (F.i = !0, E._(), D._())
            };
        return c = {
            cfg: d,
            autoSizer: E,
            loader: D,
            init: F,
            uP: w,
            aC: s,
            rC: t,
            hC: r,
            fire: v,
            gW: y,
            rAF: z
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.banner img{
 /* background: cloudinary-url("images_mobile/buy_gift_cards/buy-giftcard-banner.png", $secure: true, $fetch_format: "auto", $quality: "auto", $flags: "lossy");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;*/
  height:200px;
 /* background-size:auto 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<!-- responsive example with automatic sizes calculation: -->

<div class="banner">

  <img
    data-sizes="auto"
    data-src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/546819/pexels-photo-546819.jpeg"
    data-srcset="https://static.pexels.com/photos/546819/pexels-photo-546819.jpeg 300w,
    https://static.pexels.com/photos/546819/pexels-photo-546819.jpeg 600w,
    https://static.pexels.com/photos/546819/pexels-photo-546819.jpeg 900w" class="lazyload" />

</div>
```

Comment: Yes by this way we can do this. But can we do it with keeping that background css option as it is?

Comment: i think if i look at the documentation its only ment for `img` tags, but everything you can do with background image css you can do with the `img` tag .